# Can hidden, arbitrary XML safely be embedded in Open XML spreadsheet files?

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

**First, some background...**

I have a C# Windows application that generates files in the Excel XML Spreadsheet 2003 file format.  The files are being generate by with .NET System.XML, and not by any library designed to generate Excel files.  Such a library would be a better method I'm sure, but at this time it's not an option.

**What seems to work...**

What I've found is that I can embed arbitrary XML into the file, and both Excel and Libre Office *seem* to have no issues opening the file.  Additionally, if I save the file in Excel, it actually preserves the arbitrary XML.

**An example...**

Here is a simplified version of what my Excel XML file looks like.  Note the MyArbitraryXML section...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">

   <MyArbitraryXML>
      <RandomChildTag>Foo</RandomChildTag>
   </MyArbitraryXML>

   <Styles>
      ...
   </Styles>

   <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet 1">
      ...
   </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

As mentioned, this opens this without issue; no parse errors, no warnings, no indication there is non-standard XMLSS content in the file.

And if I save the file in Excel and still XML format, it actually retains and saves my arbitrary XML, with all tags modified to have "ss:" prepended to the tags as follows...

```
<ss:MyArbitraryXML>
   <ss:RandomChildTag>Foo</ss:RandomChildTag>
</ss:MyArbitraryXML>
```

So clearly Excel is not only parsing this XML data, it's preserving it as well.

**Why I'm doing this...**

The idea is to record some additional metadata (already in XML format) that was used to generate the Excel file.  End users of the Excel file don't need to know about the hidden XML.  If a user has a question or issue with the visible Excel data, they can send us the file and our support staff can extract the hidden XML, then reproduce the steps the user took to create the results visible in the spreadsheet.

**To my question...**

As long as I don't use tag names that are part of the XMLSS schema, is embedding this arbitrary XML actually safe to do?

Comment: One comment.  I've considered just embedding my hidden XML inside CDATA which should be 100% safe.  It should be easy enough with a custom app to pull the embedded XML out of the CDATA.

Comment: The ability to combine XML from multiple different namespaces in one document, with each app picking and choosing their own, is one of XML's (minor) selling points. Note that all the Office markup lives in its own namespace. It would be advisable to explicitly use your own namespace as well (`MyArbitraryXML xmlns="urn:TimHoltsSecretData"`) so there's no clash with other folks who want to embed their own markup (or future extensions that use "your" tag names). Whether *that* roundtrips in different apps, I don't know, but it would be more reliable if it does.

Comment: You may have more problems with Word than Excel.  A decade or so ago, Microsoft was sued over a patent about "embedded XML" in their documents. Microsoft lost.  The winner was a company named "i4i" (pronounced eye-for-eye).  You can look it up.  The problem you have is that what you are doing is not documented, so it's not supported.  If it works in 99% of the cases, there may be no work-around (or asking Microsoft) about the 1% case

Comment: Good comments.  I honestly was very surprised that what I did even worked, and that Excel actually preserved my XML.   

From our application's point of view, this ability has some interesting potential for us in terms of packing helpful information for support purposes.  

I've seen reference to customXMLParts which may be a formal way of doing what I want to do as well.